# generate meeting in webex using bookly wordpress

Tags: wordpress, webex

I am using a bookly pro to schedule a session with a practitioner and I have purchased the plan with Webex to conference meeting in video OR audio however I did not get any reference to do it in WordPress. They give me some of SDKs https://github.com/gve-sw/WebexJSSDKGuestSingleCallSharingSample Webex Meetings Scheduler/Creation sample https://github.com/gve-sw/webex_meetings_scheduler

Is there any way to integrate this in WordPress without the use of zapier?